# Hadoop Eclipse configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop

i am new to Hadoop,i successfully installed Hadoop 2.2.0 pseudo distributed mode and successfully executed some example programs like word count ,PI through command prompt ,now i want to practice some map reduce programs using eclipse ,so i installed Eclipse juno first but does not know how to configure eclipse for hadoop,can anyone tell steps to configure the Eclipse juno for hadoop 2.2.0.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to get Eclipse configured for Hadoop. Basically you need to setup the Build Path and configure Ant and Maven. There is a good write up [Here](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/05/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-hadoop-contributions/) Check that out and come back with any questions once you get started.

Even though the above link references Cloudera, the Eclipse configuration is the same as a manually installed Hadoop release as it relates to getting Eclipse working. You will need to follow steps 1 - 4 at least in order to get the correct Build Path, Ant configuration and Hadoop run time jars in the correct Path.

The easiest way to make sure you have configured Eclipse correctly is to create a Java project and copy/paste the wordcount java file into the project. Once saved take a look at any errors in the console. If you have everything correctly configured you will be able to compile worcount and should have wordcount.class in you projects bin dir

Comment: Hi Apesa, Thanks for the help, i need few clarifications on this,
actually i installed apache hadoop 2.2.0 distribution as pseudo mode not cloudera distribution ,but document above refers to cloudera,
so  i taught that cloudera and apache distibutions eclipse configurations may be same and followed same instructions given above to configure my eclipse juno ,
but while doing m2e plugin configuration, i am getting  invalid link error while trying to install it, can you please help me resolve this,
and can you please tell me what is the need of m2e plugin in the installation,Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hello, m2e is a Maven plugin for eclipse that you probably do not need. I Edited my original answer above for reference. What happens when you open Eclipse with a Hadoop java project like Wordcount?

Answer (score 0):

1.Build the project with maven(m2e plugin) and the required jar files in the classpath.
2.Export the jar for the project.
3.Use command line utility of Hadoop to execute the MapReduce Job.